# How to save html inputs into a list and display on every submission?

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

[image: Image of what I have]

I currently have what the image above show. I can enter text into the text box and click submit which post it under Result. How can I write a script where it does not overwrite the previous message? Eg; When I enter another email and hit submit it should show below of Hello@gmail.com instead of overwriting it. Also when user click submit how can I save their responses in a list corresponding to what is shown on the page? If the text gets deleted, it should remove it from the java list also.

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class EmailController {
    @GetMapping("/editprop")
    public String greetingForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", new Greeting());
        return "editprop";
    }

    @PostMapping("/editprop")
    public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute Greeting greeting) {
        System.out.println(greeting.getEmail() + "@@@@@@@@");      
        return "editprop";
    }
}
```

**editprop thymeleaf**

```
<h1>Form</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/editprop}" th:object="${greeting}" method="post">
        <p>Email: <input type="text" th:field="*{email}" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>



<h1>Result</h1>
<p th:text="'Email: ' + ${greeting.email}" />
<a href="/greeting">Submit another message</a>
```

**Pojo**

```
public class Greeting {

private String email;
//getter and setters
```

**Attempt**

For not overwriting the previous text, I decided to create a table and use th:foreach iterStat: to display each values in a list. So, my real question is how can I save the values into a list every time I click sumbit?

Answer (score 0):

- Create a list and put it onto the session.
- On submit, add the user supplied value to the list.
- On the page, loop over the list items and display them.

Adding emails to a session object:

```
public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute Greeting greeting, HttpSession session) {
  List<String> emails = (List<String>) session.getAttribute("emails");
  if (emails == null) {
    session.setAttribute("emails", emails = new ArrayList<String>());
  }

  emails.add(greeting.getEmail());
```

Looping over emails:

```
<h1>Result</h1>
<th:block th:if="${session.emails NE null}">
  <p th:each="email: ${session.emails}" th:text="'Email: ' + ${email}" />
</th:block>
```

In a real application, you'd probably store the emails in a database instead of using a session like this.

Comment: I will be implementing mongodb/ h2database in my program soon. Then I will repost. Would it be wise to save data into a db then have the view to get data from the db rather than what im doing now?

Comment: I would just retrieve all the emails on the original view (@GetMapping("/editprop"), and on the post add the email to the database and then redirect to the get, yes.